# play audio without any user interaction using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, audio

Is there any way that I can play an audio on page load , its kind of alert sound when I logged in. There will be no interaction in the web page. I understand that Google have its policy for playing like this. But does anybody have a solution for this issue.
Any suggestions would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without user interaction with the page, playing audio with JavaScript will fail with an error similar to _"Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play method is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission."_

Comment: Yes @evolutionxbox,
That is the error right now I'm facing, but is there any solution for that may be by tricking the DOM that user did interacted.

Comment: Not that I’m aware of no.